# Pyvista Challenges, Not Showing Continuous Scale And Rendering is Obfuscated

Tags: python, rendering, scale, vtk, pyvista

Newcomer to Pyvista and stackoverflow.

I'm running into issues with the color scale and rendering using Pyvista.

Here's the code, mostly boilerplate from the Pyvista documentation:

```
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

ni, nj, nk = 4, 5, 20
si, sj, sk = 20, 10, 1

xcorn = np.arange(0, (ni + 1) * si, si)
xcorn = np.repeat(xcorn, 2)
xcorn = xcorn[1:-1]
xcorn = np.tile(xcorn, 4 * nj * nk)

ycorn = np.arange(0, (nj + 1) * sj, sj)
ycorn = np.repeat(ycorn, 2)
ycorn = ycorn[1:-1]
ycorn = np.tile(ycorn, (2 * ni, 2 * nk))
ycorn = np.transpose(ycorn)
ycorn = ycorn.flatten()

zcorn = np.arange(0, (nk + 1) * sk, sk)
zcorn = np.repeat(zcorn, 2)
zcorn = zcorn[1:-1]
zcorn = np.repeat(zcorn, (4 * ni * nj))

corners = np.stack((xcorn, ycorn, zcorn))
corners = corners.transpose()

dims = np.asarray((ni, nj, nk)) + 1
grid = pv.ExplicitStructuredGrid(dims, corners)
grid = grid.compute_connectivity()


cell_centers = grid.cell_centers()
k_values = cell_centers.points[:, 2]
random_values = np.random.rand(grid.n_cells) * k_values
grid.cell_data["values"] = random_values
grid.plot(scalars="values", show_edges=True)
```

This creates the following graphic:

[Scale Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo38h.png)

Any idea why the scale is segmented and incorrect?

I also run into strange rendering issues when show_edges = False.

[Rendering Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWiaV.png)

The same issue arises with this code as well:

```
import pyvista as pv
```

pv.set_plot_theme("document")
import numpy as np

def plot_grid():
grid = pv.UniformGrid()

```
# Set the grid dimensions: shape because we want to inject our values
grid.dimensions = [10, 10, 10]

# Edit the spatial reference
grid.origin = [0, 0, 0]  # The bottom left corner of the data set
grid.spacing = [1, 1, 1]  # These are the cell sizes along each axis

# Add the data values to the cell data
grid.cell_data["values"] = np.arange(grid.n_cells)

# Now plot the grid!
plotter = pv.Plotter()
plotter.add_mesh(grid, show_edges=True, scalars="values")
plotter.add_scalar_bar(title="Cell Number")
plotter.show()
```

## Test the function

plot_grid()

[image]

Any idea why the rendering gets thrown for a loop when the edges are turned off?

Comment: I'm not familiar with explicit structured grids, but you're doing a lot of manual calculations and if you get something wrong it's plausible that VTK goes off the rails. Do you _need_ an explicit structured grid? Because your grid looks like an `ImageData` (née `UniformGrid`), or a `StructuredGrid` at worst. It would be easier to define your grid correctly with a simpler representation of the grid.

Comment: See updated question with another example. I run into the same issues. It happens across all plotting types.

Comment: This looks like a graphics driver issue. I've seen this when trying to plot under virtual machines and using old OSMesa versions on Windows. I think this is a weird hardware/driver issue specific to your system which would be tough to debug on stack overflow... Typically for PyVista bugs on GitHub we ask for a `print(pv.Report())` to help in this process